# making text input taking 12 col in a card in bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want a text input to take 12 col in card in bootstrap 4 when screen is xs but it takes only less than half

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-check-label">Date and Time</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-check-input" placeholder=" Date">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-check-input" placeholder=" Time">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the link of screenshot is here [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjUt5PVIDDujD3zukz4bA7N9HDG?e=xrM3Ti)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<div class="col-xs-12"` like below.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <label class="form-check-label">Date and Time</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-check-input" placeholder=" Date">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-check-input" placeholder=" Time">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```